# Hochschild homology with trivial coefficients: how to make $K$ an $M_n(K)$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring, $A$ an associative $R$-algebra, and $M$ an $A$-$A$-bimodule. Then the Hochschild homology of $A$ with coefficients in $M$, denoted $HH_\ast(A)$, is the homology of the chain complex 
$$\ldots\longrightarrow M\otimes_RA^{\otimes n}\longrightarrow M\otimes_RA^{\otimes n-1}\longrightarrow \ldots\longrightarrow M\otimes_RA\longrightarrow M,$$
    $$\partial_n(m\!\otimes\!a_1\!\otimes\!\cdots\!\otimes\!a_n) \;:=\; ma_1\!\otimes\!a_2\!\otimes\!\cdots\!\otimes\!a_n + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (-1)^i m\!\otimes\!a_1\!\otimes\!\cdots\!\otimes\!a_ia_{i+1}\!\otimes\!\cdots\!\otimes\!a_n + (-1)^na_nm\!\otimes\!a_1\!\otimes\!\cdots\!\otimes\!a_{n-1}.$$

1. How is the Hochschild homology of $A$ with trivial coefficients $R$ defined? We need a ring morphism $A\to R$, so that $R$ becomes an $A$-$A$-bimodule? There is no general way to do this?
2. If $A=M_n(K)=\{n\times n\text{ matrices over a field }K\}$, how is $K$ an $M_n(K)$-module?
3. Has Hochschild homology been computed for a lot of concrete examples of algebras? $R[x_1,...,x_n]$, $R\langle x_1,...,x_n\rangle$, $\Lambda_R[x_1,...,x_n]$, $M_n(R)$, Weyl algebra, generalized quaternion algebra, Clifford algebra, quasi-commutative polynomials, $R[[x_1,\ldots,x_n]]$, $K(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$?

Comment: You're asking about 10 different questions in one post — what kind of answer you're expecting?..

Comment: 1. Yes, some algebras have natural _augmentation_ $A\to R$, but it's some extra structure.

Comment: 3. Perhaps, [Hochschild-Kostant-Rosenberg theorem](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hochschild-Kostant-Rosenberg+theorem) is a good starting point.

Comment: 1. (Just in case: unlike say group homology, 'ordinary' Hochschild homology $HH(A)$ [usually] mean Hochschild homology with coefficients in $A$, not in $R$.)

Comment: Uf, come to think of it, aren't all $M_n(K)$-modules completely known up to $\cong$ via the Artin-Wedderburn theory, namely they are $S^m$ for any cardinal number $m$, where $S$ is a minimal left ideal, i.e. $\{A\in M_n(K); A\text{ has only first column nonzero}\}$? This would suggest viewing $K$ as $\{A\in M_n(K); A\text{ has only first entry nonzero}\}$.

Comment: 2. There are no non-trivial (two-sided) ideals in $Mat_n(k)$, so there are no (non-zero) morphisms $Mat_n(k)\to k$.